# Design extensible entities for a codebase

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm working currently to create a product, by that i meant an application than works on it owns but which is structured to be customizable for differents clients.

Using spring on backoffice make changing implementation of services/controller used quite easy, I just overload the bean. Client-side i have angularJS, i will probably need to restructure the module and provide some more flexibility but this should be quite easy too.

My real only problem lies with JPA/Hibernate entities.

Here is what look like my configuration :

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <array>
            <value>com.xxx.entity</value>
        </array>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyPU" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show.sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.show.sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${database.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory</prop> -->
        </props>
    </property>
    <!-- <property name="sharedCacheMode" value="ENABLE_SELECTIVE" /> -->
</bean>
```

Now let's consider the following object from the product and with two customisation for two different clients :

```
// let's say this one is the basic one
class People{ String firstName;String lastName;}
// one client want us to add one felds
class PeopleClientOne extends People{String address;}
// another define two type of very different people while having one more field common for them
class People{String firstName; String lastName;String anotherField;}
class PeopleOneClientTwo extends People{...}
class PeopleTwoClientTwo extends People{...}
```

So my question is what would be the best way to handle this considering the following restriction :

- No full abstract database model (like having one big table of entities, and one big table of attributes).
- I'm using jackson so when i have inheritance i must annotate/change annotation of the super class.
- JPA/Jackson annotations are on the same class, i don't want to duplicate classes of my model as far as possible and keep it centralized.

Here is what i though off :

Map of extensible attribute :

- Add one more table per item type that support this.
- Less readability on database
- Can't apply any constraint in database.

Usage of endorsed :

- Rewrite entities with the same package and same name and put it in endorsed folder , of course they must only add new fields.
- Database is still readable and clean
- Generally speaking usage of endorsed is not recommanded, but it's available so it can be worth.

Note i'm currently using hibernate4 but if required i can upgrade to 5. Same if your solution is with annotation instead of XML, i will probably switch to annotations later on but not today.

Any alternatives contribution, even if it's not following my requirments are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i what i end up being able :

**Get rid of the array that fix to only one package**

Define the array as a list :

```
<util:list id="entityPackages">
    <value>my.package.com.entity</value>
</util:list>
```

Use EL when injecting to convert to an array :

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="#{entityPackages.toArray()}"/>
```

Overload in the custom client module when necessary :

```
<!-- either import file containing the old one or use profile -->
<util:list id="entityPackages">
    <value>my.package.com.entity</value><!-- need to repeat that -->
    <value>my.package.com.subentity</value>
</util:list>
```

So with that you will be able to add new entities even if it's not in the same package.

**Add inheritance to entities**

In order to add properties / extend object you need to add inheritancy. For hierarchy JOIN inheritance don't cost too much as long you properly add the unique constraint and foreign key to the appropriate fields.

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
```

If you can't now because you can't modify the superclass you may have 2 alternatives :

- Use XML configuration of Hibernate
- Get the source (either the original or from the .class) or the class, add the annotation, wrap it up into a jar and put it into the endorsed folder of your server/application and don't forget to enable the endorsed mechanism.

Strictly speaking, using endorsed is dangerous and must be done really carefully. For those who don't know, when you enable endorsed mechanism, you specify a folder in which all jar files in will be loaded before every classes. Even JRE's one, so you can make sure the classes within that folder will be the one loaded instead of the ones into the others JAR.

**Jackson : use mix-in for inheritance**

Typically with Jackson you need to add the annotation @JsonSubTypes which forces you to linked your mother class with the children classes. In order to keep this class independant from this children you can use mixIn annotation :

```
// make that bean get injected the instance of jackson's mapper and called either during the initialization or just after the spring's application context was loaded.
public afterStartup() {
    myJackSonMapper.addMixIn(Site.class, SiteInheritanceMixIn.class);
}
// considering here that SubSite is inheriting from Site 
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubSite.class, name = "subSite")
})
public abstract class SiteInheritanceMixIn{

}
```